# Serialize and Reload Dynamic Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, user-controls, postback

I understand the "why" controls vanish on postback, and up until now I have had great success just creating what I need to do dynamically in page init.  However this fell apart for me when I had to add some controls to a asp.net page based on the value of an existing dropdownlist.

So my question is simple, and I don't seem to be able to find a good working code example.  I need to add some controls to the page based on the value of a dropdownlist.  Then persist these added controls across other postbacks (session is fine).

Here is a snippet to work off of:

```
    protected void Page_Init(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        RebuildPlaceholder();
    }

    protected void ddlGroup_Change(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ExampleDataContext ctxExample = new ExampleDataContext();
        var aryExample = (from rslt in ctxExample.mvExample
                          where rslt.label.ToLower() == ddlGroup.SelectedValue
                          select rslt);

        foreach (var objExample in aryExample)
        {
            TextBox txtCreated = new TextBox();
            txtCreated.ID = "ddl" + objExample.ID;
            plcExample.Controls.Add(txtCreated);
        }

        StorePlaceholder();
    }

    private void StorePlaceholder()
    {
        //Need code to store all controls in a placeholder.
    }

    private void RebuildPlaceholder()
    {
        //Need code to rebuild all of the controls from Session.
    }
```

I found this related article:  [Dynamically Adding Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871926/asp-net-dynamically-adding-controls-on-button-press-postback-issue) but I am struggling with the syntax for serializing all the controls, etc.

This can be limited to the child controls of a single placeholder that already exists on a page, just storing/restoring that placeholder's controls is what I am after.

Any version of ASP.NET is fine, if there is something that made this easy in 4.0 great.

Answer (score 0):

Instead try caching the dropdown list selection. Then during the next page load use the cache to set the value selected. Then load the new controls based on that selection.

```
Session["CacheKey"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```

Then to access the Session Cache:

```
var value = Session["CacheKey"];
```

Take a look at this Microsoft article
[on ASP.NET Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972379.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that DropDownList.SelectedValue is unavailable during Page.Init. But you can still get access to the value with `Request[ddl.UniqueID]` and then create and add all your dynamic controls.

It feels kind of like a hack, but the ASP.NET page lifecycle doesn't allow many alternatives, particularly if your controls are not serializable.